# Eclipse -Java Content assist issue

Tags: java, popup, escaping

I got a problem with the content assist in the Java-Eclipse, Windows10. During my typing codes the pop-up window opens and jumps to the very top-left corner of my screen. I have to pres ESC to be able to come back to the main editor and then I am able to continue in typing the codes. Normaly pop-up window opens right next- or below your typed codes.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it fixed. Just found the problem was with the NVIDIA QUADRO VIEW app. It works fine in Eclipse now when I deselected it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).